# I can't train a model with mobilbert or Bert in tflite-model-maker

Tags: android, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model, tflite

I'm trying to create a neural network for text classification, and according to the script from tensorflow and google, you can use MobilBert for this.
[First example - tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/modify/model_maker/text_classification) and [Second example - firebase](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/textclassification-android?hl=ru#7)
But I get an error:

```
Node: 'Adam/Cast'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNIMPLEMENTED:  Cast string to float is not supported
     [[{{node Adam/Cast}}]]
  (1) CANCELLED:  Function was cancelled before it was started
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_164585]
```

When trying other data sets, everything repeats itself, what’s the problem?

Comment: Hi @Skyain The error message you're Facing shows  that there's an issue with casting string data to float, specifically within the Adam optimizer during training. It occurs because of mismatch between the data types in your model and the optimizer. Please check your data preprocessing For text classification tasks, it's common to encode text data into numerical representations .